# How to change white images background color to black color in one folder?

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to change my images background color to black color. I tried with my own codes but it did not work, moreover it remove the object. Here is my script :

```
image = cv2.imread("./1.jpg")
r = 150.0 / image.shape[1]
dim = (150, int(image.shape[0] * r))
resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
lower_white = np.array([220, 220, 220], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_white = np.array([255, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.inRange(resized, lower_white, upper_white)
res = cv2.bitwise_not(resized, resized, mask)
cv2.imshow('res', res)
```

I will be very appreciate if anyone could help me out.Thank you.

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaS38.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using RGB color range to filter the background color you should use HSV color space. Select a hsv range to filter your background color. Here is simple implementation of the same.

```
image = cv2.imread("D:\Image\VaS38.jpg")
r = 150.0 / image.shape[1]
dim = (150, int(image.shape[0] * r))
resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
lower_white = np.array([80, 1, 1],np.uint8) #lower hsv value
upper_white = np.array([130, 255, 255],np.uint8) #upper hsv value
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(resized,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #rgb to hsv color space
#filter the background pixels
frame_threshed = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lower_white, upper_white) 

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8) 
#dilate the resultant image to remove noises in the background
#Number of iterations and kernal size will depend on the backgound noises size
dilation = cv2.dilate(frame_threshed,kernel,iterations = 2)
resized[dilation==255] = (0,0,0) #convert background pixels to black color
cv2.imshow('res', resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result image:

[image]

PS: Please note that in your case there are slight variations of HSV values near foreground object boundaries so the final result is not perfect. May be you can tune the HSV color range more precisely to get better result, or you can use foreground objects outermost edge as a limiting line to erosion.

Comment: Sorry for being late reply. You gave me the right answer to solve it, after tried several times finally it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: are you able to extract the foreground object with fine boundaries?